# File Upload with Ajax And Spring Secruity

Tags: ajax, file-upload, spring-security

After upgrading Spring Security to the 3.2.x version, the Ajax file upload function in my application is no longer working. Based on [the SS 3.2 documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipartfilter), I append ${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token} on the ajax URL. That doesn't help. I also try SS post method setting as the followings without any luck either.

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("value");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("value");

//...
$(document).ready(function() {
    new AjaxUpload('#uploadButton', { 
        action: "/shop/admin/products/images/upload",
        name: 'uploadData',
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
},
onSubmit: function(file , ext) {                

            this.disable();
            if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|JPG|PNG|JPEG|GIF)$/.test(ext))){
                alert('Error: invalid file extension');
                return false; // cancel upload
            }else {

            // change button text, when user selects file           
            button.text(msg);

            // If you want to allow uploading only 1 file at time,
            // you can disable upload button
            this.disable();

            // Uploding -> Uploading. -> Uploading...
            interval = window.setInterval(function(){
                var text = button.text();
                if (text.length < 13){
                    button.text(text + '.');                    
                } else {
                    button.text(msg);               
                }
            }, 200);
            }
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response) { 
            button.text(msg);

            window.clearInterval(interval);

            this.enable();

        }
    });
});
```

And a html related code:

```
<button id="uploadButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" th:text="#{label.upload}"></button>
```

The other option mentioned in the SS documentation is a filter configuration order. The Java configuration of the application doesn't come with any filter configuration. So this option can't be applied.

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: How do you post the file in ajax, do you use a library? What API are you using on the server side to get the file?

Comment: The Ajax file upload library was from http://valums.com/ajax-upload/. This site doesn't exit anymore. For the past few weeks, I have been trying to find a replacement of an Ajax file upload library or JQuery plug-in which works well with Spring Security 3.2 so that I could avoid this problem.

Comment: I successfully use http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ together with Spring Security 3.2.

Comment: @holmis83 Great! How do you handle Javascript code with the JQuery plug-in in a file upload to work with Spring Security?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [latest Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-caveats), the code should be `$("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content")` instead of `$("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("value")` which seems to make sense because the HTML *meta* tag has a `content` attribute instead of a `value` attribute.

Could you make this change and try again?

Comment: ... I make the change although my javascript form ajax submission is still working with the attr("value"). The change for my file upload doesn't help unfortunately. I still get the following error:

Comment: Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/store/admin/products/images/upload' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a frame at "null".  The frame being accessed is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.

Comment: This is a different problem than the CSRF token not found issue.  You seem to be using iframes for submitting information and the form submission is being denied because the `x-frame-options` header is set to `DENY` instead of `SAME-ORIGIN` in the Spring Security configuration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference. Based on Spring Security document (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html), I add one line of code to the Java configuration, After adding addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN)) to the header of http, I get a 403 error. At this point, I think I run into the uploading Spring Security setting requirement.

Comment: In my memory, I first run into a 403 error. After playing a CSRF setting in Javascript, I got the x-frame-options error.

Comment: It will be useful if you can upload a sample somewhere so that one can take a look.  Alternatively, you will have to compare your configuration files against a working sample to see where the difference is.  We have been using Spring Security 3.2 ever since it came out and have never faced any problems.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I edit my original post and have all related code posted. I haven't seen any sample code on Ajax file upload within Spring security 3.2 environment. My situation is upgrading our app to the latest Spring including Spring Security. I have made a few changes to make our app works with Spring Security 3.2. User log in and log out are some of those changes.

Answer (score 0):

A normal form, but note the hidden CSRF:

```html
<form id="myForm" action="upload" method="post"> 
  <input type="file" name="file"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload file!">
</form>
```

Ajaxify with [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/):

```javascript
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
         alert("File was uploaded!"); 
     });
 });
```

Last step for success: Make sure you have `MultipartFilter` before Spring Security in your web.xml, as described in Spring [Security reference, section CSRF Caveats](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-caveats).

jQuery Form Plugin has different strategies for file upload depending on browser, but the above should work regardless.

Comment: According to Spring Security document, either Placing MultipartFilter before Spring Security or Include CSRF token in action will take care of the problem. In your case, I believe that the first option takes place. Have you tried your code without the filter setup? What I am looking for is the second option solution.

Comment: If you use the filter setting approach, any file upload implementation should work. A solution I need is including CSRF token in action since my configuration doesn't have filter setting. I might have to look into the filter approach.

Comment: @vic With modern browsers supporting pure ajax file upload, the `xhr.setRequestHeader` strategy will work also, but beware it will fail with like old versions of IE.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I implement ajax form posting with csrf token as I am not aware of filter setting for this situation.